# Find out time stamp of Slack message from Python API

Tags: python, slack-api

I created Slack app, added Bot and Incoming Webhook to it and posted some messages with Bot. Now I would like to find out time stamp of Slack message in order to delete it later with `chat.delete` method.

I found it that I can use [channels.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) method.

Here is how I tried to use it. I used it with token found under OAuth Access Token, since per docs I cannot use Bot token with `channels.history` method.

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
slack_token_user_token = 'xoxp-long_string_of_integers'
sc_user_token = SlackClient(slack_token_user_token)

sc_user_token.api_call(
    "channels.history",
  channel="CHXXXXXXX")
```

I got back the following error:

```
{'error': 'missing_scope',
 'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'slack-route, x-slack-version-ts',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-slack-req-id',
  'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'Content-Length': '108',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'Date': 'Fri, 05 Apr 2019 18:18:11 GMT',
  'Expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer',
  'Server': 'Apache',
  'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  'Via': '1.1 f0f1092b2ad1f0e573a4fcbefe4fb621.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
  'X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes': 'channels:history',
  'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'fSm6uo2H88E43JCvqd2h5mohnzA6z0B3kmdsG3u9nW0PJNrsrpK7mg==',
  'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
  'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
  'X-OAuth-Scopes': 'identify,bot,incoming-webhook',
  'X-Slack-Req-Id': 'c158668d-ddc9-4bbc-9a7d-6b9a9011d2dc',
  'X-Via': 'haproxy-www-yfr6',
  'X-XSS-Protection': '0'},
 'needed': 'channels:history',
 'ok': False,
 'provided': 'identify,bot,incoming-webhook'}
```

If this is permission issue, how do I find out proper token to use?

Comment: As I said on your other question: I strongly recommend to post your message via API method ' chat.postMessage'  and not use the webhook if you want to later delete it.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, what makes you think this is webhook, I do have webhook enabled, so you see in `provided` field, but I am no longer using HTTP Post method directly. Sorry, I am also lost in terminology. I am using this tutorial: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message you posted the token used is lacking the required scope.

> 'needed': 'channels:history'

It looks like you provided the bot token, which can not work.

> 'provided': 'identify,bot,incoming-webhook'

Provide the access token and make sure you first add the `channel.history` scope and reinstall the app to activate.

Comment: Actually, pure Bot token returned: `'provided': 'identify,bot:basic'`, but adding permissions on `Basic Information `helped`